# Trying to retrieve information from Eurostat using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I find myself regularly needing information for economics statistics from Eurostat in order to train and test an inference model.

I tried automating the process using **Requests** and **BeautifulSoup**;

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': '*/*'
}

page = requests.get('https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?dataset=sts_inpr_m&lang=en', headers=headers)
return BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

As a reply though I am getting:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/jquery-1.3.2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/noMultipleWindows.js?d=1594493775728'></script>
  <form id='firepost' method='POST' action='https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?dataset=sts_inpr_m&lang=en&fbclid=IwAR0wiAQfEomg6H-OfRlAgbLI5laWbqXr0W5QjeT89I_MOvaQiQUIDEx5XBg'>
   <input type='hidden' name='dataset' value="sts_inpr_m"/>
   <input type='hidden' name='fbclid' value="IwAR0wiAQfEomg6H-OfRlAgbLI5laWbqXr0W5QjeT89I_MOvaQiQUIDEx5XBg"/>
   <input type='hidden' name='lang' value="en"/>
  </form>
  <form id='errorForm' method='POST' action='https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/onewindowpersession.do'>
  </form>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    blockOrAllowProceed();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

How can I (if possible at all) make **BeautifulSoup** get the content from the specified location?

Comment: That means the website knows you are a bot

Comment: What do you mean by content? The text inside an element? Or a value from the element itself? And in which specific location are you interested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url specified is not a get request. It's a post request with the json body as in the code below

```
data = {"dataset":"sts_inpr_m","lang":"en"}
res = requests.post("https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?dataset=sts_inpr_m&lang=en", json=data)
print(res.text)

return BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
```

Output:

```
\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n    <title>Eurostat - Data Explorer</title>\r\n    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">\r\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>\r\n    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>\r\n    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>\r\n    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/css/nui.css"/>\r\n    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/css/layout.css"/>\r\n    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/css/tabs.css"/>\r\n    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/css/estat.css"/>\r\n    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/css/dataTable.css"/>\r\n    <link type="text/css" href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>\r\n    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/css/ajaxTree.css"/>\r\n\r\n    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/images/favico.ico"/>\r\n</head>\r\n<body class="Bodyid30038601siteid0" id="body">\r\n    <div id="dialog">\r\n        <p style="text-align: center;">Please wait while your request is being processed</p>\r\n        <img src=\'https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/images/loader.gif\' alt=\'loading...\'\r\n             style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div id="modifyTableDialog">\r\n        <p style="text-align: center;">Please close the modify selection dialog or click update.</p>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>\r\n    \r\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/noMultipleWindows.js?d=1594495067683"></script>\r\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/ui.core.js"></script>\r\n    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/ui.dialog.js"></script>\r\n    <script type="text/javascript">\r\n        jQuery.noConflict();\r\n        jQuery("#dialog").dialog({\r\n            height: 100,\r\n            minHeight: 100,\r\n            modal: true,\r\n            closeOnEscape: false,\r\n            autoOpen: false,\r\n            title: \'Processing\'\r\n        });\r\n        jQuery("#dialog").dialog(\'open\');\r\n\r\n        jQuery("#modifyTableDialog").dialog({\r\n            height: 80,\r\n            minHeight: 80,\r\n            modal: true,\r\n            closeOnEscape: false,\r\n            autoOpen: false,\r\n            title: \'dimension modification dialog open\'\r\n        });\r\n    </script>\r\n    \r\n    <!-- header div -->\r\n    <div id="head">\r\n        \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<script type="text/JavaScript">\r\n    function refresh_language(newLanguage) {\r\n        var cLangName = \'userlanguage\';\r\n        var expDays = 90;\r\n        var exp = new Date();\r\n        exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (expDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));\r\n        expirationDate = exp.toGMTString();\r\n        var newCookies = cLangName + \'=\' + newLanguage + \'; expires=\' + expirationDate;\r\n        document.cookie = newCookies;\r\n        location.reload(true);\r\n    }\r\n</script>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<div id="eurostatDiv">\r\n\t<div id="eurostatLogoDiv" class="Bodyid1116533siteid0">\r\n\t\t<img src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/images/ext_site5_header.png" alt="Eurostat" border="2" /><br />\r\n\t</div>\r\n\t<div id="eurostatLegalNoticeDiv" style="text-align: right;">\r\n\t\t\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<script defer src="//europa.eu/webtools/load.js" type="text/javascript"></script>\r\n<script type="application/json">\r\n{\r\n\t"utility" : "piwik", \r\n\t"siteID" : 229, \r\n\t"sitePath" : ["appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu\\/nui"], \r\n\t"lang" : "en", \r\n\t"siteSection" : "data explorer"\r\n}\r\n</script>\r\n\r\n\r\n<div style="float:right; text-align:right;">\r\n\t<a id="eurostatLegalNoticeLink" href="http://ec.europa.eu/geninfo/legal_notices_en.htm" target="_blank">Important legal notice</a>\r\n\t<div id="nuiVersionSpan">v3.6.2-20200506-bdabf-ESTAT_LINUX_PROD</div>\r\n\t <div id="nuiIntstanceId" style = "text-align:center;">DATA-EXPLORER_PRODmanaged21</div>\r\n</div>\r\n\t</div>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n\r\n    </div>\r\n\r\n    <!-- tabs div -->\r\n    <div id="tabsdiv">\r\n        \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/css/header.css"/>\r\n\r\n<!--[if IE 6]>\r\n<style>\r\n#nav ul.left li.selected a{\r\n    color: white;\r\n    background-color: #0199CB;\r\n}\r\n#nav ul{\r\n    top:3px;\r\n}\r\n</style>\r\n<![endif]-->\r\n\r\n<script type="text/javascript">\r\n    function callBack(action, dimension, displayMode) {\r\n        parent.left.ModifyTable_changeParams(action, dimension, \'_parent\', displayMode);\r\n    }\r\n\r\n    function UpdateSelectionInfo() {\r\n        try {\r\n            if (parent.left.ModifyTable.findUserChanges() == false) {\r\n                popup.show(\'selectedCodes\');\r\n                return true;\r\n            }\r\n        } catch (e) {\r\n        }\r\n        return false;\r\n    }\r\n\r\n    function openInformationWindow(prefix) {\r\n        var windowHeight = 280;\r\n        var windowWidth = 525;\r\n        var location = "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/NodeInfoServices?lang=en&code=sts_inpr_m";\r\n        return window.open(location, \'Information\'+prefix, \'height=\' + windowHeight + \',width=\' + windowWidth +\',location=no,status=no\');\r\n    }\r\n</script>\r\n<div id="nav">\r\n    <ul class="right">\r\n        <li class="metadata">\r\n            \r\n                \r\n                    \r\n                        \r\n                        \r\n                            <a target="_blank" href="http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/metadata/en/sts_esms.htm">\r\n                                Explanatory texts (metadata)\r\n                            </a>\r\n                        \r\n                    \r\n                \r\n                \r\n            \r\n        </li>\r\n        <li class="information">\r\n            \r\n                \r\n                    <a target="_blank"\r\n                       onclick="if(UpdateSelectionInfo())return false; var w=openInformationWindow(\'_3762712c-26b4-4038-b072-5ecf073f1b2c-1594495066183_\');w.focus();false;">\r\n                        Information\r\n                    </a>\r\n                \r\n                \r\n            \r\n        </li>\r\n        <li class="download">\r\n            <a target="_top" onclick="if(UpdateSelectionInfo())return false;"\r\n               href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/setupDownloads.do?p=3762712c-26b4-4038-b072-5ecf073f1b2c-1594495066183_">\r\n                Download\r\n            </a>\r\n        </li>\r\n        <li class="preview">\r\n            <a href="#" onclick="javascript:\r\n                    if (UpdateSelectionInfo()==true) {\r\n                        return false;\r\n                    } else {\r\n                    \r\n    \r\n                    \r\n                        window.open(\'/nui/print.do?p=3762712c-26b4-4038-b072-5ecf073f1b2c-1594495066183_&print=true\',\'PrintPreview_3762712c-26b4-4038-b072-5ecf073f1b2c-1594495066183_\',\'toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1\');\r\n                    }">\r\n                Preview\r\n            </a>\r\n        </li>\r\n        <li class="bookmark">\r\n            <a target="_top" onclick="if(UpdateSelectionInfo())return false;"\r\n            \r\n               href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/setupBookmark.do?p=3762712c-26b4-4038-b072-5ecf073f1b2c-1594495066183_">\r\n                Bookmark\r\n            </a>\r\n        </li>\r\n        <li class="demo">\r\n            <a target="_blank" href="http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/help/demo-tours">\r\n                Demo\r\n            </a>\r\n        </li>\r\n        <li class="help">\r\n            <a target="_blank"\r\n               href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/pages/main/demo/demo_en/html/index.html">\r\n                Help\r\n            </a>\r\n        </li>\r\n        \r\n            \r\n            \r\n                <li class="login">\r\n                    <a target="_top" href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/login.do">Login</a>\r\n                </li>\r\n            \r\n        \r\n    </ul>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<div style="clear: both;"></div>\r\n<div id="coloredBar" class="current"></div>\r\n<div style="width: 98%; margin: auto;">\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n    \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n       \r\n\r\n  \r\n       \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/css/datasetInfo.css;jsessionid=jkU_T-BFvXVQLl6StE_DeyK7S5Wh8g9LZUtov8IIkzWPKw2V58xu!349483206"/>\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n<div id="dataset_info_dl" style="display: none;">\r\n    <span class="closeBtn" href="#">&nbsp;</span>\r\n\r\n    <p style="text-align: center;">\r\n        Production in industry - monthly data\r\n    </p>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<div id="datasetDescription">\r\n    <div class="user_info right_side">\r\n        \r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class="dataset_info">\r\n        <span class="left_side">\r\n            \r\n                \r\n                \r\n                    Production in industry - monthly data\r\n                \r\n            \r\n        </span>\r\n\t\t        \r\n        <span class="right_side">\r\n            [sts_inpr_m]\r\n            <span style="display:none;">prefix: [p=3762712c-26b4-4038-b072-5ecf073f1b2c-1594495066183_]</span>\r\n        </span>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class="subTitle clear">\r\n        <span>\r\n            \r\n        </span>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class="shortDescription">\r\n        \r\n        \r\n    </div>\r\n    <div class="update_info">\r\n        <table id="obsoleteCode" style="margin-top: 0px; font-size: 8pt; height: 10px">\r\n\t\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t\t<td style="text-align: justify; width: 200px; margin: 0; ">\r\n\t\t\t\t  Last update:\r\n\t\t\t\t  10-07-2020  \t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t<!-- \r\n\t\t\t\tDATAEXPL-826\r\n\t\t\t\t<td  style="white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: top;">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t      \r\n\t\t\t\t</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t-->\r\n\t\t\t</tr>\r\n\t\t</table> \r\n    </div>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n    </div>\r\n\r\n    <!-- contents div -->\r\n    <div id="contents">\r\n        \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<style type="text/css">\r\n    html, body { overflow: hidden; }\r\n</style>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<noscript>\r\n    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?p=3762712c-26b4-4038-b072-5ecf073f1b2c-1594495066183_&wai=true&dataset=sts_inpr_m" />\r\n</noscript>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n    \r\n        \r\n        \r\n    \r\n\r\n    \r\n        \r\n        \r\n    \r\n\r\n    \r\n        \r\n        \r\n    \r\n\r\n    \r\n        \r\n        \r\n    \r\n\r\n    \r\n        \r\n        \r\n    \r\n\r\n    \r\n        \r\n        \r\n    \r\n\r\n    \r\n        \r\n        \r\n    \r\n\r\n    \r\n        \r\n        \r\n    \r\n\r\n    \r\n        \r\n        \r\n    \r\n\r\n    \r\n        \r\n        \r\n    \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<script type="text/javascript">\r\n    var xtCornerColWidth = 112;\r\n    var cornerDivColWidth = 106;\r\n    var COL_WIDTH = 106;\r\n    \r\n    function getContextPath(){\r\n    \treturn \'/nui\';\r\n    }\r\n</script>\r\n\r\n<!-- include prototype and Scriptaculous -->\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/prototype.js"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"\r\n        src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/scriptaculous/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,dragdrop"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/nuidragndrop.js"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/labelcodes.js?d=1594495067685"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/footnotes.js?d=1594495067685"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/SDC_ContextMenu.js?d=1594495067685"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/SDC_Core.js"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/SDC_Table.js"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/SDC_Dragndrop.js"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/SDC_Tree.js"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/resize.js"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/tableHover.js"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/PT_LongDragSupport.js"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/PT_PackedTableAccess.js?d=1594495067685"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/PT_RenderTable.js?d=1594495067685"></script>\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/js/PT_EventHandlers.js?d=1594495067685"></script>\r\n\r\n\r\n  \r\n       \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">\r\n\tvar dataIndex="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";\r\n\tvar dataValues="105.3|105.7|105.3|104.8|103.1|105.0|105.1|93.6|77.4|(s):|104.8|105.1|104.8|104.3|102.8|104.4|:|:|:|:|103.8|104.0|103.6|103.1|101.3|103.2|103.1|90.8|75.3|(s):|116.9|115.4|113.1|114.3|116.8|111.9|112.6|106.2|89.7|:|106.8|107.2|108.3|107.3|105.5|107.8|108.7|103.2|91.2|91.1|(p)111.9|113.3|113.2|112.0|111.0|111.9|112.3|100.1|76.9|87.6|110.2|112.6|109.7|104.1|111.8|107.6|109.2|108.6|102.4|101.4|100.4|99.6|98.7|99.5|97.9|99.7|100.1|89.4|71.3|78.2|112.1|109.7|108.6|110.1|109.3|107.3|117.4|106.1|97.2|97.0|95.3|98.6|102.7|98.1|92.1|94.2|94.4|114.4|101.2|(p)91.3|(p)108.7|(p)109.9|(p)107.0|(p)102.5|(p)105.9|(p)110.6|(p)106.3|(p)108.3|(p)98.9|(p):|106.3|(p)105.7|(p)105.3|(p)105.7|(p)104.8|(p)104.5|(p)104.2|(p)90.1|(p)69.6|(p)80.1|(p)103.0|103.6|103.9|103.5|101.1|102.0|102.9|86.0|68.5|:|104.9|106.9|105.8|105.2|103.0|104.3|104.1|102.6|96.9|93.5|105.1|104.7|104.4|104.6|101.7|105.5|104.4|74.7|59.4|84.4|131.9|133.2|133.4|131.8|132.1|132.8|134.2|116.0|83.0|:|118.9|120.1|117.6|116.2|115.9|113.7|117.1|112.4|104.1|109.2|117.8|120.5|117.6|121.5|119.2|115.9|114.4|116.4|105.5|112.8|101.2|(s)99.3|(s)96.8|(s)95.3|(ps)92.0|(ps)96.2|(ps)96.4|(ps)79.8|(ps)68.4|(ps)75.2|(ps)114.7|118.4|117.7|116.2|112.0|117.3|117.2|105.0|73.0|84.4|108.4|(p)105.5|(p)105.5|(p)105.9|(p)109.4|(p)112.0|(p)110.6|(p)103.9|(p)99.9|(p):|101.9|103.1|102.8|101.7|100.1|102.8|(p)101.8|(p)100.8|(p)94.2|(p)93.5|(p)111.6|113.2|112.0|109.9|110.0|115.6|111.8|104.5|87.8|(p):|119.2|120.7|122.2|124.0|120.3|123.9|125.3|116.0|91.5|102.9|103.5|100.8|104.3|103.2|106.5|107.1|104.1|95.2|76.8|78.6|112.9|113.5|111.3|111.2|111.0|(p)113.8|115.4|101.1|73.1|(p):|123.5|(p)124.1|(p)125.9|(p)124.8|(p)122.6|(p)123.9|(p)128.5|(p)114.5|(p)97.6|(p):|110.2|111.6|111.6|111.8|110.1|115.2|114.3|91.1|66.8|:|114.4|113.7|113.0|113.2|113.1|111.4|112.0|114.5|112.0|:|112.0|110.9|109.9|111.4|109.9|111.3|111.2|111.2|94.6|(p)94.1|(p)101.6|101.6|101.8|100.7|100.6|100.4|100.3|96.1|76.6|:|93.8|94.3|97.2|99.7|101.0|98.5|101.1|102.4|101.7|100.6|116.1|118.1|117.5|116.9|111.0|118.0|115.6|113.3|:|:|109.6|(s)114.8|(s)106.0|(s)109.8|(s)124.2|(s)118.1|(s)104.4|(s)113.7|(s)69.3|(s):|115.2|115.6|114.7|110.2|108.0|114.0|114.6|103.6|75.4|82.8|111.1|111.9|112.0|113.3|112.9|115.0|113.4|108.3|91.6|100.4|112.1|115.9|114.9|115.8|117.9|117.6|119.8|111.6|77.7|:|100.8|101.8|99.6|102.3|100.1|104.1|102.1|95.4|89.3|91.1|";\r\n\tvar xIndex="0000000000000034000000680000009c000000d000000104000001380000016c000001a0000001d400000208";\r\n\tvar xValues="0|TIME2019M08|106|0|0|TIME|2019M08|2019M08|2019M08|01|TIME2019M09|106|1|0|TIME|2019M09|2019M09|2019M09|02|TIME2019M10|106|2|0|TIME|2019M10|2019M10|2019M10|03|TIME2019M11|106|3|0|TIME|2019M11|2019M11|2019M11|04|TIME2019M12|106|4|0|TIME|2019M12|2019M12|2019M12|05|TIME2020M01|106|5|0|TIME|2020M01|2020M01|2020M01|06|TIME2020M02|106|6|0|TIME|2020M02|2020M02|2020M02|07|TIME2020M03|106|7|0|TIME|2020M03|2020M03|2020M03|08|TIME2020M04|106|8|0|TIME|2020M04|2020M04|2020M04|09|TIME2020M05|106|9|0|TIME|2020M05|2020M05|2020M05|0";\r\n\tvar yIndex="000000000000005100000098000000db000000fc0000011e0000013f00000160000001aa000001cb000001ec0000020e0000022f000002510000027400000295000002b7000002d9000002fe0000032400000347000003680000038f000003b2000003d4000003f80000041b0000043f0000046300000486000004a8000004d2000004f40000051b000005410000056c0000058e000005b0000005e2";\r\n\tvar yValues="0|GEOEU27_2020|106|0|0|GEO|EU27_2020|European Union - 27 countries (from 2020)||01|GEOEU28|106|1|0|GEO|EU28|European Union - 28 countries (2013-2020)||02|GEOEA19|106|2|0|GEO|EA19|Euro area - 19 countries  (from 2015)||03|GEOBE|106|3|0|GEO|BE|Belgium||04|GEOBG|106|4|0|GEO|BG|Bulgaria||05|GEOCZ|106|5|0|GEO|CZ|Czechia||06|GEODK|106|6|0|GEO|DK|Denmark||07|GEODE|106|7|0|GEO|DE|Germany (until 1990 former territory of the FRG)||08|GEOEE|106|8|0|GEO|EE|Estonia||09|GEOIE|106|9|0|GEO|IE|Ireland||010|GEOEL|106|10|0|GEO|EL|Greece||011|GEOES|106|11|0|GEO|ES|Spain||012|GEOFR|106|12|0|GEO|FR|France||013|GEOHR|106|13|0|GEO|HR|Croatia||014|GEOIT|106|14|0|GEO|IT|Italy||015|GEOCY|106|15|0|GEO|CY|Cyprus||016|GEOLV|106|16|0|GEO|LV|Latvia||017|GEOLT|106|17|0|GEO|LT|Lithuania||018|GEOLU|106|18|0|GEO|LU|Luxembourg||019|GEOHU|106|19|0|GEO|HU|Hungary||020|GEOMT|106|20|0|GEO|MT|Malta||021|GEONL|106|21|0|GEO|NL|Netherlands||022|GEOAT|106|22|0|GEO|AT|Austria||023|GEOPL|106|23|0|GEO|PL|Poland||024|GEOPT|106|24|0|GEO|PT|Portugal||025|GEORO|106|25|0|GEO|RO|Romania||026|GEOSI|106|26|0|GEO|SI|Slovenia||027|GEOSK|106|27|0|GEO|SK|Slovakia||028|GEOFI|106|28|0|GEO|FI|Finland||029|GEOSE|106|29|0|GEO|SE|Sweden||030|GEOUK|106|30|0|GEO|UK|United Kingdom||031|GEONO|106|31|0|GEO|NO|Norway||032|GEOCH|106|32|0|GEO|CH|Switzerland||033|GEOME|106|33|0|GEO|ME|Montenegro||034|GEOMK|106|34|0|GEO|MK|North Macedonia||035|GEORS|106|35|0|GEO|RS|Serbia||036|GEOTR|106|36|0|GEO|TR|Turkey||037|GEOBA|106|37|0|GEO|BA|Bosnia and Herzegovina||0";\r\n\tsetPackedTableStructures(dataIndex,dataValues,xIndex,xValues,yIndex,yValues);\r\n</script>\r\n\r\n<div id="DivShim"></div>\r\n<div id="tooltip1"></div>\r\n\r\n<form id="TableViewForm" name="TableViewForm" action="https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/submitViewTableAction.do;jsessionid=jkU_T-BFvXVQLl6StE_DeyK7S5Wh8g9LZUtov8IIkzWPKw2V58xu!349483206" method="post">\r\n    \r\n    <!-- CSS for hidden columns -->\r\n    <style type="text/css">\r\n    \r\n        @import url(https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/ajaxTableView.do?i=3&p=3762712c-26b4-4038-b072-5ecf073f1b2c-1594495066183_&hidencols=);\r\n    </style>\r\n    <div id="datasetNameContainer" style="width: 98%; margin: 0 auto;">\r\n        <fieldset style="margin: 0;">\r\n            <legend>\r\n                Table Customization\r\n                <span id="showHideTableCustomization" style="color: #0199CD; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">\r\n                    show\r\n                
....
.....
```